# Contract creation with "new" fails, creates EOA not contract account

Tags: solidity

Mist 0.8.6, solidity 0.4.2+commit.af6afb04.mod.Emscripten.clang:

I am trying to create a contract within a contract, but the contract created with "new" is not created as contract but as EOA (Address).

Is this a problem of that compiler version or am I doing something wrong?

Simple code example:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;

  contract ContractB {
    string private name;

    function set_name(string _name) {
      name = _name;
    }

    function get_name() returns(string) {
      return name;
    }
  }

  contract ContractC {
    string private name;

    function set_name(string _name) {
        name = _name;
    }

    function get_name() returns(string) {
        return name;
    }
  }

  contract ContractA {
    ContractB public contractBvar;
    ContractC public contractCvar;

    // Constructor
    function ContractA() {
        contractBvar = new ContractB();
        contractBvar.set_name("contractB");
    }


    function createContractC() {
        contractCvar = new ContractC();
        contractCvar.set_name("contractC");
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

seems morden ist just slow. the problem solved itself after a while. now its a contract account in etherscan: https://testnet.etherscan.io/address/0x0aA0bcdF51502c0f66950707e1D8Ac84Cf6dF3ea